# Python - Ctypes CFUNCTYPE crashes in ARM devices

Tags: python, callback, crash, ctypes, buildroot

I'm trying to register a python callback to be called from my C code using Ctypes. Everything works fine on my computer, but python crashes when the code runs in an ARM device.
In my computer I'm using python 3.6.6 and this ARM device uses python 3.6.3. I'm using buildroot to generate the images.

Well, after some tests seems that the problem is related to CFUNCTYPE.
The following code only test the CFUNCTYPE, and it runs on my computer but crashes (segmentation fault) on the ARM device:

```
    from ctypes import *

    def func():
        print("func called")

    CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(None)

    callback = CALLBACK(func)

    print("Calling callback")
    callback()

    print("Done!")
```

The result in my computer is:

```
Calling callback
func called
Done!
```

The result in the ARM device is:

```
Calling callback
Segmentation fault
```

Is this a bug in CFUNCTYPE? Or I need to do something different? I'm running a lot of python code in this device and everything runs fine, except this CFUNCTYPE.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, this works calling the callback on Windows with both 32- and 64-bit Pythons.  I normally only call callbacks like this from C but calling from Python works on Intel architecture.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: Yes, seems like a bug. I'll also call this from C. This is only a short example to activate the bug. I found an alternative solution using Cython. I created a cython file between my python and C code. This way I can register the callbacks in a similar way.